# How to properly use lang in HTML

Tags: html, lang

I want to ask you how to properly use lang in HTML code.
Im trying to have website in 2 langs en, pl.

```
<html lang="en">
<html lang="pl">
```

Is this way correct?

Comment: you cannot use two html elements

Comment: So, correct way will be like..  <html lang="en"> <lang="pl"> or <div> one?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two `<html>` tags in the same document. You should use one `<html>` tag without the `lang` attribute and use the `lang` attribute on tags that contain only one language. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--some elements in the head-->
</head>
<body>
    <p lang="en">This is text</p>
    <p lang="fr">Ceci est du texte</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

If the document’s *primary* language is in, say, Polish with large parts that are in English, then it should have `<html lang="pl">` with `<div lang="en">` or something around the English parts:

```html
<html lang="pl">
…
<body>
[Polish content]
    <div lang="en">
        [English content]
    </div>
[more Polish content]
    <div lang="en">
        [more English content]
    </div>
[more Polish content]
…
```

Regardless the `html` element should if possible always have a `lang` value, [per the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element):

> Authors are encouraged to specify a `lang` attribute on the root `html` element, giving the document's language. This aids speech synthesis tools to determine what pronunciations to use, translation tools to determine what rules to use, and so forth.

But if a document is such a mix of languages that it can’t really be seen as having a single *primary* language, [then the `html` element *still* should have a `lang` attribute, but with an *empty* value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attr-lang):

> Setting the attribute to the empty string indicates that the primary language is unknown.

```html
<html lang="">
…
<body>
    <div lang="pl">
        [Polish content]
    </div>
    <div lang="en">
        [English content]
    </div>
    <div lang="pl">
        [Polish content]
    </div>
    <div lang="en">
        [English content]
    </div>
    …
```

For more detailed information on this, see the following W3C guides:

- [Declaring the overall language of a page](https://www.w3.org/International/techniques/authoring-html#textprocessing)
- [Choosing language tags](https://www.w3.org/International/techniques/authoring-html#langvalues)